# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS showing 'version message write failed' message while booting

Tags: 14.04, boot, bug-reporting

The following lines are getting displayed while Ubuntu is booting.

```
[   27.981086] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[   27.985007] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: version message write failed: ret = -5
[   27.985071] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: hbm_start failed ret = -5
[   27.985123] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: reset failed
[   27.985166] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: link layer initialization failed.
[   27.985224] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: init hw failure.
[   27.987404] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: initialization failed.
```

I've been using it for around 4-5 months now and this is the first time I got this message. I'm able to log in and everything seems to be working fine.
But this error message is bugging me.

Is there a way to fix this.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE #1**

Added `blacklist mei` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` but the error is still being displayed on boot.

Comment: Bug confirmed on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1450813

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added `blacklist mei_me` line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

The error message is not showing while booting. The speed of booting hasn't increased; it is taking the same amount of time as before(when the error message was being shown).

Answer (score 0):

The module `mei` is the driver for [Intel(R) Management Engine Interface](http://intelmanagementengine.com/intel-technologies/all-about-intel-management-engine-interface.html).

[Some examples of Intel AMT usage are:](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/misc-devices/mei/mei.txt)

- Monitoring hardware state and platform components
- Remote power off/on (useful for green computing or overnight IT
   maintenance)
- OS updates
- Storage of useful platform information such as software assets
- Built-in hardware KVM
- Selective network isolation of Ethernet and IP protocol flows based
   on policies set by a remote management console
- IDE device redirection from remote management console

To get rid of the error  just blacklist the module with

```
sudo echo  "blacklist mei_me" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

[source and more info](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Resolve_mei:_Init_hw_failure_or_mei:_initialization_failed)

Comment: It's still showing the error.

Comment: check the edit. `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Checked.

'blacklist mei' is there.

Comment: in the blacklist.conf?

Comment: have you try a reboot?

Comment: Yes. How else would I know?

Comment: you want to know what?!

Comment: Nothing. The error is still showing on boot.

Comment: This is what i found for your problem...

Comment: Actually the module name you need to blacklist is `mei_me` not `mei`.

Comment: Using `>` redirection is a REALLY bad idea. You're overwriting everything in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and then writing that single line. Like the other commenter noted, [this can have disastrous effects.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/616734/ubuntu-14-04-lts-showing-version-message-write-failed-message-while-booting#comment876807_618153)