# Is Intel accessing my machine without permission through mei_mei module?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616734/ubuntu-14-04-lts-showing-version-message-write-failed-message-while-booting), there's a module called mei_me which allows Intel to update my machine remotely.
Does this mean that, whenever I'm online, they have the ability to access my machine without my permission? (perhaps only if my machine is registered?)

If so, I'm guessing that there's nothing that any operating system can do to stop this, as it's in firmware, beneath any operating system, correct?

*By the way, I would have posted a comment on an answer, but I can't comment yet: there appears to be typos in a couple of answers: the command:*

```
echo "blacklist mei_me" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

*would wipe out everything else in the `blacklist.conf` file. It should be:*

```
echo "blacklist mei_me" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: the MEI is for *you* (or your IT team) to access your machines for remote/automated/offline management. Not for Intel, tinfoil hats aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMT includes basic security scheme[[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology#Security)] using either security certificate, pre-shared key or password.

You could do a simple check if AMT/MEI is enabled on your PC. Try to access your own pc with `http://<your_pc_ip>:16992` from a browser on another pc on your LAN (beware of your firewall if there is any).

It looks like this:
[image: default home page of AMT remote management]

The best info I have found so far is from the *amt-howto* [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man7/amt-howto.7.html) from **amtterm** package. I encourage you to read it.

From what I understand, AMT must be enable in the BIOS/EFI (using CTRL-P to access the config page). It is only in that case that your PC is reachable via AMT.

If AMT is enabled, you can disable it in the BIOS/EFI. If it is and using SMB (or password scheme), there is a default password of **admin**. You can also change the default password to something of your liking to prevent remote access.